# How to disable SparkUI programmatically?

Tags: apache-spark

I noticed that this bug has been fixed:

> Allow users to disable Jetty Spark UI in local mode
>
> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2100

but how to disable it programmatically?

is it by

```
sparkContext.setLocalProperty(?, ?)
```

I checked the documentation, but couldn't figure out which property to set

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-ui

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Set `spark.ui.enabled` to `false`. This configuration isn't documented on Spark's configuration page because it was added as an internal configuration for debugging and unit tests [1].

With spark-submit, you could simply `--conf spark.ui.enabled=false`.

[1] https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/2363/files#r17436782

Answer (score 0):

@jacek - Even after enabling spark.ui.enabled to false in spark defaults ( verified it is available in node ) and still UI is accesible. Any clues? I am looking to disable the UI